# Can Alexa skill handler receive full user input?

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit

I want to develop an Alexa skill that is able to receive free text input from the user that doesn't necessarily map to an intent. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not possible. The closest thing is the 'literal' slot (input) type but that is now deprecated on the original USA region and was never supported on the other regions.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the custom slots return far more than the provided samples.